# How to reduce viewstate size of server control?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have developed a server control which inherits from `CompositeDataBoundControl` and `INamingContainer`. It has 2 TextBoxes and 1 small image.

But when rendering in `GridView` its ViewState size is up to 500 bytes. It also has about 20 properties, but I don't use ViewState here.

I only use `get;set;` and I bind it again when postback.

Now I am wondering how to reduce this ViewState size and how I can examine this ViewState . If I can examine the values of ViewState , it would be helpful to fix the problem.

Comment: By the way, it's not just CompositeControl. It's CompositeDataBoundControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the ViewState into a [base-64 decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/). I always find it enlightening to see what is taking up the space.

Keep in mind that the ViewState field also includes [ControlState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422240/cant-turn-off-viewstate-asp-net-vs2010-what-can-be-wrong/9422383#9422383).

> It has got 2 TextBoxs and 1 small image.

Some controls can function quite well without ViewState, due to their constant presence in the HTTP request. A `TextBox` is a good candidate for explicitly disabling ViewState because its value is always posted back to the server as part of the request.

An image is also a good candidate for disabling ViewState, unless calculating the URL requires processing time (e.g. a database call versus static assignment).

> But when rendering in GridView...

A `GridView` almost definitely adds to the ViewState itself. Are you accounting for that?

Comment: Thx, Tim. It's been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you could disable the viewstate with

```
this.EnableViewState = false;
```

you could also check this link [Disable View State for a Page](http://www.ironspeed.com/articles/Disable%20View%20State%20for%20a%20Page/Article.aspx) to disable a viewstate from a page.

If you wish to check the viewstate, you could use [ASP.NET ViewState Helper](http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/02/aspnet-viewstate-helper) or a tool such as Fiddler to analyze the viewstate.

Comment: Thx, hagensoft. But I am a server control developer, I cannot tell all the developers to disable viewstate. And my point to is what are the tips to reduce viewstate size, not turning it off.

Comment: Here are some strategies that may help you to help reduce the size of a viewstate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944218/strategies-for-reducing-viewstate-size-in-asp-net